# How can I check when a JFrame has been closed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How do I check when `JFrame` window is closed?

```
MediaPanel mediaPanel=new MediaPanel();
JFrame_of_subtitle frame=new JFrame_of_subtitle(mediaPanel);
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will add [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) to your frame.

WindowListener has a [windowClosing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) callback function which will be invoked when your frame is being closed.

You can see this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) for sample code.